# Deletion and cleanup in Redis

Tags: redis

Say I maintain a set to define membership for "articles" in "tag" groups.

If I delete an article, is it up to me to manually cleanup any references to the article in sets, or any sets that are specifically associated with the now-deleted article?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. The reference you are referring to is only exists at the application level. Redis does not provide support for reference nor cascading actions. So you need to handle it in your application manually.

Comment: Thank you. So people typically implement the relevant logic at the application level, for example in query-objects? I am concerned about keeping this maintainable...

Comment: Yes, somewhere in application like data access layer, caching layer, etc.

Comment: Manually managing data relationships like this must be error-prone. Do people just live with the fact that "garbage" will accumulate in a redis store?

Comment: People tends to use Redis as a cache store as you can specify a TTL on a key so they can be cleaned out automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I am considering using Redis, with persistence turned on, as the "database" (as opposed to a straightforward caching layer) for a simple  news website. Is there anything fundamentally wrong with this idea?

Comment: You can of course use Redis as a persistent database and people have done that too. It is not a wrong idea at all, it is just a different idea. Using it as a persistent database would require more work on your side of course. Like every thing in life, if it is done right, it would be as good as any others.

Comment: Final question! Is it typical to use a convention for key generation permitting O(1) object retrieval at a later time? Is key generation solely application-level responsibility? eg. the id `users:1` would have to be generated by application logic, with application logic ensuring the next user added is "users:2" (ie. doesn't conflict). Perhaps a hash is used instead of incrementing to avoid this kind of problem?

Comment: @BenAston it is entirely up to you on how you want your key naming scheme works. You need to have a good one to avoid any possibility of key conflicts. And of course a smart scheme that can save you time from looking up for them. However you want to do it, it's up to you.